# Assembly visible in Package Explorer but not referenced when installed

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I am creating a NuGet package from one of my projects using `-IncludeReferencedProjects`.

When I check the nupkg afterwards with the NuGet Package Explorer I see all referenced libraries inside the lib folder.

After installing the package in another project one of the before mentioned projects is not referenced.

I don't get any error messages when installing or packaging. Does anyone have an idea, what might cause this or is there a way to debug it somehow?

The Nuget package is hosted in our Team Services repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem was that the assembly name was ending with .Resources for some reason .Net or Visual Studio or NuGet can't handle that.